# Get a list of numbers from a list of complex terms

Tags: prolog

I have a list of complex terms with the same functor and arity, but different arguments. Something like this:

```
Elements = [element(a, 1), element(b,2), element(c,3)]
```

And from it I wish to generate a new list, containing only second arguments of the each complex  term in the list, like this:

```
Numbers = [1,2,3]
```

Is there a way to design the predicate to solve this problem for any length of the input list?

Comment: Yes, this is very straight-forward. Do you have any attempts? Hint: you can make use of `element(_, N)` will provide all values of `N` on backtracking. Also, have a look at `findall` or `setof`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, already spent couple of hours with no result (I'm very new to Prolog). Most of my attempts were spinning around `element(_,N)`, but I find out that I understand how to make use of it only for a known number of arguments, which is not the case here. I'll try to use `foreach` & `setof`, thanks for the advice.

Comment: That's `findall` not `foreach`. ;) If you show your attempts, you'll get more help on SO. :)

Comment: Given your `element/2` predicate, to solve for any length you just define a recursive predicate as you would for any other list processing purpose.

Comment: Finally solved with `findall`! Thank you, I'll post the solution. Now I'm wondering how to solve it with recursion.

Comment: Okay as a newbie I'm not allowed to post answers to my own questions, so here is a solution:
`findall(X,member(element(_,X), Elements),Numbers)`.

Comment: @Timofey recursive:
    `element_indexes([], []).
    element_indexes([element(_,N)|Es],[N|Ns]) :-
        element_indexes(Es, Ns).`
I forgot that thing about not being able to post on your own question when you're newly signed up. I was figuring, since you were so close, you'd figure it out and start earning yourself some rep. ;)

Comment: Using `findall` will be incorrect when variables occur in place of the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timofey's answer with `findall/3`: `findall(X,member(element(_,X), Elements),Numbers).`

Solution with a recursive predicate:

```
element_indexes([], []).
element_indexes([element(_,N)|Es],[N|Ns]) :-
    element_indexes(Es, Ns).
```

Comment: @Timofey: please click on accept button, marking this answer as useful. It's the better way to gain reputation on SO !